Blender Rig always importing -90 on the X into Unity
I am trying to export a model from Blender and into Unity. No matter what I set the Armature settings as in the FBX export, the rig always imports in at -90 on the X axis in Unity. All Transforms in Blender are applied. Any idea what might cause this?
Note: I have also tried disabling the FBX setting of apply transforms.
Screenshot showing that everything is applied in Blender:

FBX Export Settings:

Unity Import:


